# What's the right replacement for PostEvent

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

I'm getting a warning that `PostEvent` is deprecated and I assume that one is supposed to use `PostEventToQueue` but it takes two extra parameters and I can't find any documentation on what combination of parameters (one is a queue specification, the other is an event priority) will be equivalent to `PostEvent`.

Comment: Please only use the xcode tag for problems related to XCode itself, and not programming issues related to the language/OS that you are developing for.  I have removed it and added the cocoa tag for you.

Comment: @Inafziger, I can't see any reason why the Cocoa tag is relevant either.

Comment: It's part of the Cocoa API so not unreasonable, perhaps even more reasonable than "osx" to some extent.

Comment: @David, what's part of Cocoa?  PostEvent is part of Carbon, and the replacement CGEventPost is part of Quartz Event Services.

Comment: Fair enough --- but this is really nitpicking ---- I'd really just like an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PostEventToQueue` is for a Carbon Event, not a low-level OS event like `PostEvent`.  If you want to post a keyboard or mouse event, you should use `CGEventPost`.

Edit to add:  To post a mouse down at the current location, I think (untested) that you can do this:

```
CGEventRef theEvent = CGEventCreate( NULL );
CGEventSetType( theEvent, kCGEventLeftMouseDown );
CGEventPost( theEvent );
CFRelease( theEvent );
```

Comment: So what is the equivalent CGEventPost call to the deprecated call in  the JUCE code with which I'm experimenting. The call is  PostEvent (::mouseDown, 0);

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestion. Pity to have to replace a single call with four calls though!

Comment: What's your source for the statement that `PostEventToQueue` is deprecated? Both the header and the Carbon Event Manager document don't mention a deprecation.

Comment: Also, don't forget to forge a mouse-*up* to go with that mouse-down. Some apps that consume events at a lower level than usual, like those that run under Wine or otherwise under X11, may not react well with only half of the pair—and, for that matter, there's no guarantee that all Cocoa apps will be able to make sense of it, either.

Comment: Oh, one more thing: There is a `CGEventCreateMouseEvent` function, which enables you to specify all of the facts that a mouse-related event requires in a single call. The location, in particular, may be important for a mouse-down event. ☺

Comment: @PeterHosey:  OK, I guess `PostEventToQueue` is not technically deprecated, I thought it was because its documentation is marked "Legacy".  And yes, if you know the mouse location you want to use for the event, `CGEventCreateMouseEvent` would be a better choice.

Comment: @Peter --- I'm just wanting to replace a single line  PostEvent(::mouseDown,0) in an existing example because xcode is telling me it's deprecated. There doesn't seem to be a location. Given that the eventMsg is 0, I don't actually understand what it means to post a mouseDown event without a location.

Comment: @David: “The `PostEvent` function fills out the `when`, `where`, and `modifiers` fields of the event structure with the current time, current mouse location, and current state of the modifier keys and mouse button.” You will have to get and provide the current mouse position—or use specific coordinates of your choosing, such as the center of some object on the screen—yourself. (Also, [for `mouseDown`, the message is undefined](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/mac/Toolbox/Toolbox-37.html#HEADING37-0).)

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be reasonable to assume that using the event queue returned by `GetMainEventQueue()` (or `GetCurrentEventQueue` if you're on the main thread), and `kEventPriorityStandard` for the priority, will get you results equivalent to `PostEvent`.

Be aware, though, that these only affect your own application. Even the old Event Manager probably doesn't have access to an “Operating System event queue” anymore—I wouldn't be surprised if it's just a wrapper around the Carbon Event Manager version. You'd need to switch to CGEvent stuff if you want to post events that can hit other applications.